# How to compute random bfloat number in Maxima CAS

Tags: random, precision, maxima

[Maxima Cas random function](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_10.html#IDX378) takes as an input floating point number and gives floating point number as an output.

I need [floating point number with more digits](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Time_series_of_the_Tent_map_for_the_parameter_m%3D2.0_made_with_increased_precision.svg), so I use bfloat with increased precision.

I have tried :

```
random(1.0b0)
bfloat(random(1.0));
```

The best result was :

`bfloat(%pi)/6.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b0
5.235987755982988730771072305465838140328615665625176368291574320513027343810348331046724708903528447b-1`

but it is not random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to generate a random bigfloat is to generate an integer with the appropriate number of bits and then rescale it to get a number in the range 0 to 1.

Note that `random(n)` returns an integer in the range 0 to n - 1 when n is an integer, therefore: `bfloat(random(10^fpprec) / 10^fpprec)`.

Comment: are any other possibilities?

Comment: One could, I suppose, work in Lisp, and generate a number of bits and then directly construct a bigfloat, instead of doing arithmetic. That would be more nearly the same thing as what the current code for ordinary floats is doing.

Comment: Here is the code which uses random bfloat: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Time_series_of_the_Tent_map_for_the_parameter_m%3D2.0_made_with_increased_precision.svg